# Laravel 9 and jQuery only showing data of datatable first row

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I have a datatable list with different categories. I created an edit button on every row using "foreach", the button popups a modal that shows a form with the data of every category. In this form I have 2 dropdowns, the first shows the sections to which each category belongs and the second droopdown should show every category that belongs to that section. I created a jQuery that updates the second dropdown to show that categories, the problem is it will only work with the first row of the datatable.

This is the button that triggers the jquery

```
<a class="updateLevel" catId="{{ $category['id'] }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#edit{{$category['id']}}"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil-outline" style="font-size:22px;"></i></a>
```

This is the jQuery

```
    $(document).on("click",".updateLevel",function(){
        var catId = $(this).attr('catId');
        alert(catId);
        $.ajax({
            headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type:'get',
            url:'append-categories-level',
            data:{catId:catId},
            success:function(resp){
                // alert(resp);
                $("#appendCategoriesLevel").html(resp);
            },error:function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is the function in the controller I am using

```
    // Append Level
    public function appendCategoriesLevel(Request $request){
        
        if($request->ajax()){
            $catId= $request->catId;
            $category = Category::find($catId);
            $getCategories = Category::where(['parent_id'=>0,'section_id'=>$category['section_id']])->get()->toArray();
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($getCategories);
            return view('admin.categories.append_categories_level')->with(compact('getCategories'));
        }
    }
```

Here is the dropdown HTML

```
<div class="mb-1">
    <label class="form-label" for="parent_id">Nivel</label>
    <select name="parent_id" id="parent_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Principal</option>
        @if(!empty($getCategories))
            @foreach($getCategories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category['id'] }}">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my datatable

```
                    <table id="categories" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Categoría</th>
                                <th>Categoría Padre</th>
                                <th>Sección</th>
                                <th>URL</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Acción</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                            @if(isset($category['parentcategory']['category_name'])&&!empty($category['parentcategory']['category_name']))
                                @php $parent_category = $category['parentcategory']['category_name']; @endphp
                            @else
                                @php $parent_category = "Ninguno"; @endphp
                            @endif
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $category['id'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $category['category_name'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $parent_category }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $category['section']['name'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $category['url'] }}</td>

                                <td>@if($category['status']==1) <a class="updateCategoryStatus" id="category-{{ $category['id'] }}" category_id="{{ $category['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="mdi mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline" style="font-size:22px;" status="Active"></i></a> @else <a class="updateCategoryStatus" id="category-{{ $category['id'] }}" category_id="{{ $category['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="mdi mdi-minus-circle-outline" style="font-size:22px;" status="Inactive"></i></a> @endif</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="updateLevel" catId="{{ $category['id'] }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#edit{{$category['id']}}"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil-outline" style="font-size:22px;"></i></a>
                                    <a class="confirmDelete" module="category" moduleid="{{ $category['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="mdi mdi-close-circle-outline" style="font-size:22px;"></i></a>
                                    @include('admin.categories.edit')
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I tried debugging my code, and saw that I am getting the values for each one of the datatable rows

For example this would be for the first row (Which is working fine and populating the dropdown)

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [section_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Ropa Mujeres
            [description] => Ropa para Mujeres
            [category_image] => 
            [category_discount] => 0
            [url] => womensclothing
            [meta_title] => womensclothing
            [meta_description] => womensclothing
            [meta_keywords] => womens clothing
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2022-12-22T22:08:27.000000Z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [section_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Accesorios
            [description] => Accesorios de Mujer
            [category_image] => 
            [category_discount] => 0
            [url] => womensaccesories
            [meta_title] => womensaccesories
            [meta_description] => womensaccesories
            [meta_keywords] => womens accesories
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2022-12-22T21:50:19.000000Z
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 0
            [section_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Zapatos
            [description] => Zapatos de Mujer
            [category_image] => 
            [category_discount] => 0
            [url] => womensshoes
            [meta_title] => womensshoes
            [meta_description] => womensshoes
            [meta_keywords] => womens shoes
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2022-12-22T14:31:06.000000Z
        )

)
<div class="mb-1">
    <label class="form-label" for="parent_id">Nivel</label>
    <select name="parent_id" id="parent_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Principal</option>
                                    <option value="1">Ropa Mujeres</option>
                            <option value="2">Accesorios</option>
                            <option value="3">Zapatos</option>
                        </select>
</div>
```

and this would be for the row number 5 which is not populating the dropdown

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_id] => 0
            [section_id] => 1
            [category_name] => Ropa Hombres
            [description] => Ropa para Hombres
            [category_image] => 
            [category_discount] => 0
            [url] => mensclothing
            [meta_title] => mensclothing
            [meta_description] => mensclothing
            [meta_keywords] => mens clothing
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 2022-12-22T02:54:20.000000Z
            [updated_at] => 2022-12-22T22:08:37.000000Z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 0
            [section_id] => 1
            [category_name] => Accesorios Hombres
            [description] => Accesorios para hombre
            [category_image] => 
            [category_discount] => 0
            [url] => accesorioshombre
            [meta_title] => accesorioshombre
            [meta_description] => accesorioshombre
            [meta_keywords] => accesorios hombre
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 2022-12-23T02:03:29.000000Z
            [updated_at] => 2022-12-23T02:03:29.000000Z
        )

)
<div class="mb-1">
    <label class="form-label" for="parent_id">Nivel</label>
    <select name="parent_id" id="parent_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Principal</option>
                                    <option value="4">Ropa Hombres</option>
                            <option value="5">Accesorios Hombres</option>
                        </select>
</div>
```

Here is the controller

```
public function appendCategoriesLevel(Request $request){
    
    if($request->ajax()){
        $catId= $request->catId;
        $category = Category::find($catId);
        $getCategories = Category::where(['parent_id'=>0,'section_id'=>$category['section_id']])->get()->toArray();
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($getCategories);
        return view('admin.categories.append_categories_level')->with(compact('getCategories'));
    }
}
```

Here is what I get when I click on the first row
[image]
and this is in the first row
[image]

Clearly, I am getting the data, but they are only populating for the first row. I also tried adding an else statement to the dropdown html to see if its empty and it is for every row except the first one.

Comment: Checking the network tab in your request, is the correct HTML being sent there?

Comment: If it is the one that is at the end of the arrays I posted, then yes.

Comment: 1) show the controller function that sends the data to the frontend.
2) I would add that dropdown button in the data that you send to the frontend
3) show the data (at this moment) that you have in the frontend
4) show your datatables function in the frontend

Comment: I think so u have to change the name and I'd of two Drop-down.

Comment: Not working either